# Проверка дизайна на разных моделях Android

Tags: android

Как проверить сразу на нескольких устройствах (нет физических устройств, только эмуляторы), что правильно расположил все графические элементы? Пытаюсь найти в приложении изъяны дизайна. Возможно, где-то фото не так растягивается, а иконка не там отображается. Есть какие-либо варианты?

Answer (score 4):

Визуальный редактор *Android Studio* имеет режим отображения разметки *Preview All Screen Size* (крайняя левая иконка без подписи в визуальном редакторе) , который может дать примерное представление, как будет выглядеть та или иная разметка на разных экранах:

[image: screen]

Последний пункт этого меню *Toggle Layout Mode* позволяет переключать режимы отображения: общий вид всех экранов (как на скриншоте) или один крупным планом, остальные меньше - кликая на меньшие экраны можно рассмотреть его "поближе".

Данный режим дает лишь примерное и не всегда верное представление, как все будет выглядеть на реальном устройстве, но все же достаточно экономит времени, чтобы не запускать кучу эмуляторов по каждому изменению разметки.
Окончательное тестирование лучше выполнять на реальном устройстве или эмуляторе.

PS: так же тут можно посмотреть, как все будет выглядеть на всех объявленных локалях или на всех версиях андроид, для которых установлены SDK в *SDK Manager* и еще несколько режимов, которые тоже могут оказаться полезными, так что рекомендую ознакомиться с этим меню получше.

Answer (score 0):

Эмуляторов для этого вполне хватит. Кстати, советую использовать Genymotion как альтернативу стандартному эмулятору. Особенно уделите внимание проверке вёрстки на устройствах с разной плотностью пикселей. Посмотрите, как ваше приложение будет выглядеть на 7" и 10" планшетах, если они представляют для вас интерес. Предпросмотр в графическом режима редактирования layout'ов в Android Studio тоже может дать примерное представление, но доверять ему точно не стоит. Не все нюансы он покажет. А какого-то автоматизированного способа проверить всё это, не трогая ничего руками, кажется и нет.