# Адаптивная верстка под все экраны android

Tags: java, android, ui

Подскажите пожалуйста , очень много гуглил и  почти нигде не сказанно, о том что можно сделать полностью адаптирующися дизайн под все экраны не зависимо от плотности и диагонали. То есть получаем ширину, высоту экрана и на их основе все остальные элементы растягиваются под своими коэфицентами. Про то что на большом разрешение элементы растянутся и будет плохое качество, решается добавлением в проект более детализированных картинок. Какие минус у данного способа по сравнению с версткой нескольких layout-ов.

Comment: Все эти механизмы адаптивной верстки уже встроены в android (атрбуты разметки match_parent, wrap_content и подобное), не требуется получать какие то размеры экрана и что то самому высчитывать, все прекрасно изложено в документации, так же как и в любой литературе по android, также и на [этом ресурсе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628961/177345).  Несколько layout требуется только если различная компоновка для разных экранов (телефоны/планшеты, например). Картинки выбираются с помощью [системы квалификаторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483204/177345).

Comment: Недавно [представленный `ConstraintLayout`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345) позволяет создать полностью адаптивный одноуровневый макет

Comment: Да именно ConstrainLayout использую, но программно прописываю ширину и длину элементам зависимо от разрешения экрана, вариант с опорными линями интересен, но если элементов много, и не всегда подойдет две линии .

Comment: Абсолютные значения в верстке экранов android не используются **практически никогда**, так же как и программное вычисление их размеров самому. Все это делает система без вашего непосредственного участия. Конкретно в ConstraintLayout есть кроме опорных линий [инструмент chains](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642642/177345). Больше [о верстке в ConstrainLayout](https://constraintlayout.github.io). В ответах по ссылкам из моих комментариев есть так же достаточное количество ссылок, чтобы полностью раскрыть тему адаптивной верстки, тема затерта до огромных дыр.

Comment: Если у вас проблема с конкретной ситуацией верстки, приведите макет, что вы хотите сверстать и у вас не получается, вся общая теория изложена в достаточном объеме, чтобы писать еще один ответ.

Comment: Все получается, хотелось узнать, спасибо

Comment: если все получается через *"но программно прописываю ширину и длину элементам зависимо от разрешения экрана"*, то это не правильное и не рациональное решение, на самом деле все намного проще.

Comment: Не подскажите , насчет размера текста(шрифта) можно его как то в том же xml адаптировать?

Comment: Размер шрифта задается, как правило , через единицы *sp* - плотности, не зависящей от масштабирования. Данный ресурс не предполагает каких то общих рассуждений на широкие темы (как вообще верстать ..). Если у вас конкретная проблема, которую вы не можете решить - изложите ее в вопросе: что получается не правильно, что ожидается, приложите разметку\код и прочее, что поможет понять в чем именно проблема. Еще [один ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) по теме адаптивной верстки, там и про шрифт немного писал.

Comment: Я говорю про то что, пользуясь моим методом , я определяю размер текста (шрифт) тоже отталкиваясь от ширины и длины от родительского элемента(TextView) , разметка в layout всегда по умолчанию берёт один шрифт и не зависимо от размера элемента TextView будь он на весь экран или же занимает 10% от него. текст одиного размера, что не удобно так как в одном случае текст может выйти за рамки, в других быть слишком мелким.

Comment: Такое действительно возможно, например, при использовании "телефонной" разметки на планшете, так как отношение размер экрана\плотность у них существенно отличается от телефона. Для таких случаев используется указание размера шрифта для виджета не константным значением, а через [параметр `dimen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620551/7566397), само значение в ресурсе `dimens` указывается для определенного экрана через квалификатор (например, для планшета файл *dimens.xml* в папке *res/values-sw600dp/*). Все это тоже изложено в документации и по ссылке в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: Но по факту, как итоге если делать разметку через xml то она получается  делается в какой-то момент на интуитивном уровне для телефонов, планшетов 7-8  и 9+ дюймов, как для элементов , так и для шрифта текстов нужно примерно подбирать чтобы на всех экранах было норм( или же делаться для минимального разрешения для данной плотности), поэтому мой вопрос  и состоим в том какие минусы несёт мой метод, кроме как что он делается программно не через xml( не по феншую), хотя мне очень нравится ConstraintLayout намного лучше Relative.

Comment: Ничто не мешает оттестировать на основных типах устройств, в том числе эмуляторов, если нет физических. Так же предварительно оценить [можно уже в визуальном редакторе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451048/177345). Ваш способ плох тем, что создает большое количество "ненужного" в контроллере (активити) кода, которому там, в общем то не место, он "забивает" логику контроллера и ухудшает сопровождение.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под сопроваждением , да этоь недосток очень большой( забивание клнтроллера кучей кода)

Comment: Сопровождение - улучшение, добавление функциональности в программу, исправление ошибок и тп. Если вам понадобится что то изменить на экране, потребуется очень много времени и нервов, чтобы разобраться, что же и где делалось с разметкой в коде и потом внесение правок в нескольких местах, из за чего высоковероятны ошибки. Если бы проще было все делать через код - никто бы не заморачивался с дополнительной системой квалификаторов и подобным.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше терпение , теперь намного лучше понимаю в верстке под андроид. Огромное вам спасибо

Comment: Если у вас нет конкретной проблемы, решить которую не помогло сказанное выше, в том числе по ссылкам, то я закрою ваш вопрос на уже существующий по этой теме? Если все же есть какая то проблема или что то из изложенного не понятно, то изложите это в вопросе, чтобы можно было дать объективный ответ, отличный от уже имеющихся по этой теме.

Comment: Закрывайте, вопрос иссерпан