# Тестирование Activity для разных экранов

Tags: android

Как лучше тестировать активити для разных размеров экранов. 
Сейчас я пытаюсь создавать разные эмуляторы с различными комбинацией Density/size

Например hdpi-normal.  На данный момент Density перебираю от mdpi до xxxhdpi, а size normal и large.
Возможно существует какие-то рекомендованные комбинации свойств экрана, на которых стоит проверить? Или существует специальные методы по такому тестированию?

Comment: Где-то встречалась компания, которая специализировалась на тестировании приложений заказчиков на разных девайсах - у них был набор из сотни разных моделей смартфонов/планшетов со всеми возможными экранами, клавиатурами и проч. вывихами, которые нормальный девелопер никогда себе не смог бы вообразить. Рассказывали, что чаще всего приложения валились на девайсах с физическими клавиатурами и отсутствием камеры - тупо вылетали NPE :)

Comment: Предварительно можно быстро и удобно оценить [встроенными средствами визуального редактора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451048/177345)

Comment: к сожалению, мне этот метод не подходит так как многие размеры определяются в момент формировании окна